# Can't deploy war on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gradle

I've a Spring Messaging app that I've developed inside of eclipse using a local instance of Tomcat 8. This works perfectly fine from inside eclipse, however when I create a war and deploy it inside the `webapps` directory of Tomcat it doesn't work.
These are the steps that I've done till now.
I'm using a gradle build system, on a windows machine. Thus I ran `gradlew build`.
This generated a `war` file inside `root/build/lib`
I went to the bin directory of my local tomcat and ran `start.bat`
This set Tomcat running, then I copied the war to the `webapps` directory of tomcat.
All I get is a `404`.

This is my catalina.log

```
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.857 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.858 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.859 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.36.0
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.859 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 8.1
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.859 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.3
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.859 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.859 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.859 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-b14
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\conf\logging.properties
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\endorsed
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\temp
07-Sep-2016 10:32:21.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AccuRev\bin;C:\common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;%MAVEN_HOME/bin%;C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Dev\gradle-2.13\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Users\SG047329\AppData\Roaming\npm;.
07-Sep-2016 10:32:22.029 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Sep-2016 10:32:22.094 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
07-Sep-2016 10:32:22.096 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
07-Sep-2016 10:32:22.104 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
07-Sep-2016 10:32:22.105 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 524 ms
07-Sep-2016 10:32:22.130 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
07-Sep-2016 10:32:22.130 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
07-Sep-2016 10:32:22.223 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\opl-ws-webui-0.1.0.war
07-Sep-2016 10:32:29.090 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
07-Sep-2016 10:32:33.793 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\opl-ws-webui-0.1.0.war has finished in 11,570 ms
07-Sep-2016 10:32:33.795 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\docs
07-Sep-2016 10:32:33.826 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\docs has finished in 30 ms
07-Sep-2016 10:32:33.826 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\examples
07-Sep-2016 10:32:34.734 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\examples has finished in 908 ms
07-Sep-2016 10:32:34.735 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\host-manager
07-Sep-2016 10:32:34.775 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\host-manager has finished in 40 ms
07-Sep-2016 10:32:34.776 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\manager
07-Sep-2016 10:32:34.811 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\manager has finished in 35 ms
07-Sep-2016 10:32:34.811 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\ROOT
07-Sep-2016 10:32:34.835 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat\v8\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\ROOT has finished in 24 ms
07-Sep-2016 10:32:34.839 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Sep-2016 10:32:34.856 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
07-Sep-2016 10:32:34.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 12765 ms
```

I've a few questions here,

1. How do I deploy the war and get it to run inside Tomcat.
2. When I run inside eclipse, I don't see any war actually being created inside `build/lib`, so how is eclipse using Tomcat to run my webapp anyway?

Comment: Did you check the Tomcat log files? Should be named something like `catalina.log` in the `logs` folder of Tomcat.

Comment: Edited the question to add the catalina.log

Comment: Open Tomcat Manager app to check whether your application is running or not. In my case, it wasn't running even after clicking Start in manager app console because I had web.xml errors. Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like your `opl-ws-webui-0.1.0.war` started fine. Without any more information, it should be served under the same name as the war file, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/opl-ws-webui-0.1.0/`, but you can confirm the name by looking at the Tomcat Manager, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/manager/`

Comment: @Andreas that did it. I was running http://localhost:8080/opl-ws-webui/ and thus getting a 404. The version affix solved it.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Actually the way yo start a clean Tomcat instance is:

- Stop Tomcat Server
- Clean logs, temp and work folders
- Copy your .war file to the webapps folder
- Start Tomcat

  If this process does not work you can see the files generated in the tomcat    logs files to see why this is not starting

2.- Eclipse as well as other IDE's like IDEA use directly the webapp, build folder of your application, not the .war file.
The war file contains inside this webapp folder which is unzipped when you start just tomcat.

Comment: Edited the question to add catalina.log